# Physical HDD size

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sony-vaio

My father poses a [Sony Vaio VGNTZ150N](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/model-documents.pl?mdl=VGNTZ150N). The computer has a SSD drive and he would like to upgrade it to a larger drive. I cannot see the computer physically and I would like to advise him whether he needs a 1.8" or 2.5" for his computer.

Where can I find the information?

---

Followed Linker3000's advice and got the following from the device manager:
`mcboe32gqapq`

I read that it is a Samsung SSD 32 1.8" with a ZIF interface. Can someone confirm this please?

Comment: It's probably 2.5 but most 1.8 come with a 2.5 adapter so you can't go wrong with a 1.8 (they do cost more and hold less). By the way I read the manual and there is absolutely nothing about the physical size of the drives in it. You might just want to call Sony...

Comment: Have him take the drive out and measure it... XD
 Good Luck!

Comment: Nice @david simplest way to figure it out ^

Comment: @Shaihi, Where did you read that, the second result from Google? If you scroll down a bit, you’ll also find some references to that drive being 2.5". Which revision is your drive? Some extra looking indicates that there are a few revisions (MWA, MWA00, MXA, OXAOO), though unfortuanetly, the most common one (MWA) seems to have references for both 1.8" and 2.5".

Comment: @Synetech: One of the results in google.... Problem is I cannot open the computer and I only have the device manager to check for the serial number...

Comment: Well the serial number should give the exact model and revision, which should help pinpoint which size it. Worst case scenario, you could email the HD mfg with the serial number and ask them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can guide him into the Device Manager (assuming the laptop is running Windows), you can at least get the part number of the current drive and then look up its specs

Answer (score 0):

It's probably 2.5 but most 1.8 come with a 2.5 adapter so you can't go wrong with a 1.8 (they do cost more and hold less). By the way I read the manual and there is absolutely nothing about the physical size of the drives in it. You might just want to call Sony.. Or measure as David said, "measure it."